# My browser keeps refreshing

Tags: php, html, if-statement

After I created an if inside a SELECT tag (HTML) my browser keeps refreshing.
The purpose of this if is to make an OPTION selected when the condition appear.
I also have done this earlier on the same page and it worked.

My guess is that having the 2 SELECT dropdowns on the same page, having this code is making them to refresh each other (I have a jQuery to do onchange actions).

the code is this:

```
<select name="ddequipamento" id="ddequipamento" class="cliente" <?  if (!$_GET['id']) echo "disabled"  ?> >
<option value="---">---</option>
<?
    if ($_GET['id'])
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count_equipamento; $i++)
        {   
            $idequipamento = mysql_result($result_equipamento,$i,"idequipamento");
            $marca = mysql_result($result_equipamento,$i,"marca");
            $tipo_equipamento = mysql_result($result_equipamento,$i,"tipo_equipamento.tipo_equipamento");
            $num_serie = mysql_result($result_equipamento,$i,"num_serie");

            echo  (' <option value="'.$idequipamento .'" ');

            if ($_GET['eq'] = $idequipamento){
                echo  (' selected="true" ');
            }

            echo (' >'.$tipo_equipamento. ' - '. $marca . ' - '. $num_serie .'</option>');
        }
    }

?>
<option value="0" >Novo</option>
</select>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $('#ddcliente').change(function () {
       window.location.href = "index.php?id="+ $(this).val();
    });    

});
```

Comment: I suggest to add the HTML and JS in your question.

Comment: Probably better to show you javascript code. PHP is server side.. unless you are using a header statement it won't refresh the page loaded in your browser

Comment: Are you submitting something? that cause the page to refresh ?

Comment: why everyone always blames PHP for their HTML issues :-(

Comment: sorry, uploaded some more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please pass "eq" through URL , Please change it in script,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {  
      $('#ddcliente').change(function () {
        window.location.href = "index.php?id="+ $(this).val()+"&eq=<?php echo $_GET['eq'];?>";
     });    
 });
```

If you want to "id" only then  change in PHP part,

```
  if ($_GET['id'] = $idequipamento){ //OLD if ($_GET['eq'] = $idequipamento){
            echo  (' selected="true" ');
   }
```

IF TWO DROPDOWNS WITH DIFFERENT ID  "eq" and "id"

if you have 2 drop-downs use,

```
  $(document).ready(function () {  
       $('#ddcliente').change(function () {
           window.location.href = "index.php?id="+ $(this).val()+"&eq=<?php echo  $_GET['eq'];?>";
       }); 

       $('#ddcliente2').change(function () { //CHANGE THE ID OF SECOND DROPDOWN
          window.location.href = "index.php?eq="+ $(this).val()+"&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>";
       });    
  });
```

and also change the PHP part for 2 drop-downs

```
   // FIRST DROP DOWN
   if ($_GET['id'] = $idequipamento){ //OLD if ($_GET['id'] = $idequipamento){
        echo  (' selected="true" ');
   }
   // SECOND DROP DOWN , CHANGE VARIABLE NAME of $idequipamento2
   if ($_GET['eg'] = $idequipamento2){ //OLD if ($_GET['eq'] = $idequipamento){
        echo  (' selected="true" ');
   }
```

Comment: my bad, changed code after and still auto refreshing. can't seem to find the problem here

Comment: Please make sure id, and "eg" are correct in each dropdown, I have just edited code , please check it now

Comment: Please change the variable name also from above code (mentioned as comments)